# Family of indexed sets

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

[image: sets]

I am having trouble grasping the concept of an index family set. Here we have intersection and union, and from what I gather about the concept the answers should be as follows.

$a.$ empty set

$b.$ all real numbers set

$c.$ empty set

$d.$ (-1,3)

---

From the solutions the correct answer reads

$a.$ {0}

$b.$ all real numbers

$c.$ [0,1]

$d.$ (-1,3)

Any help would be appreciated, as it seems I'm having difficulty grasping the intersection vs. the union.

Answer (score 1):

a. $0$ belongs to all sets $(-1/n,1/n)$, hence also to their intersection.

c. $[0,1]$ is contained in all sets $(-1/n,1+1/n)$, hence also to their intersection.

In both cases, it is clear they are "maximal", so it is exactly their intersection.

Ps. It seems you have difficulty only with intersections, but you understood unions. If this is the case, then use the identity
$$
\bigcap_{i \in I}A_i=\left(\bigcup_{i \in I}A_i^c\right)^c,
$$
and you are always back to unions.

Comment: Did not know about that identity, thank you. So 0 belongs to all sets, I understand why it is an intersection for $a$ and $c$, but why is the 1 there? Is it because $1 + 1/n$ will always be greater than 1, so 1 is included in the intersection?

Comment: Yes: a point belongs to the intersection of a family of sets if and only if that point belongs to all such sets

Comment: Thank you for clearing that up!

Comment: What value of $n$ does $1\over n$ give zero? Elsewhere in the exercise it's implied that $n \in \mathrm{R}$. However $\infty$ is not a real number.

Comment: @Χpẘ.  No value of $ n$ gives $1/n=0.$ In (a) we have ($-1/n,1/n)=\{x\in \mathbb R: 1/n>|x|\}.$  The number $0$ is a member of each set $(-1/n,1/n).$

Comment: @Daniel Sorrry, I don't get how zero is a member of (a) if there is no value of $n$ for which $(-1/n,1/n)$ yields zero.

Comment: @Χpẘ. In this context (-1/n,1/n) is not an ordered pair. It is the set of all numbers between -1/n and 1/n . Zero is one of the numbers that belong to this set.

Comment: @Daniel Thanks. I guess I need to look up that notation. I guess parenthesis here mean an open interval, so the notation means the intersection of all the open intervals $(-1/n,1/n)$ where $1 \geq n$.

Comment: @Χpẘ. You may also see ]a,b[ to denote an open interval an ]a,b] to denote a half-open interval. The trouble with (a,b) is that it is used for many different things.

Comment: @Daniel And the lesson learned for me, is to be more careful about assuming what the meaning $(a,b)$ is. BTW for anyone reading these comments, my previous comment should have said $1 \leq n$

Comment: @Χpẘ. I have also seen <a,b> to denote an ordered pair. But <a,b> also has other meanings.